# ASP NET Core Minimal API always returns 200 instead of specified 204

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

Even when I say return 204 (NoContent), it returns 200. Why?

```cs
app.MapGet("/api/alive", (context) => Task.FromResult(new StatusCodeResult(204)));
```

Status code in browser is 200

Comment: Can you show more of your code please so we can see how youre getting to this response.  Typically I would expect to see `Return NoContent();`

Comment: It makes no difference if you Use Results.NoContent(), new NoContentResult() or new StatusCodeResult(204)

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)? Are you aware of the signature of second argument(`RequestDelegate`) ? Where did you get that it has a return type?

Comment: Changing the type to RequestDelegate did the trick

Comment: Do not edit the answer into your question. I have rolled back your question to the original version.

Comment: ok, didn't know it would be a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to change the signature a bit:

```cs
app.MapGet("/api/alive", () => Results.NoContent());
```

(context) alone does not work,
Edit: as well as (RequestDelegate context) does not work.

```cs
app.MapGet("/api/alive", (context) => Results.NoContent());
app.MapGet("/api/alive", (RequestDelegate context) => Results.NoContent());
```

Comment: Really frustrated with this. Is it a bug? Is there a work around? Trying to map to a handler function so I can use attributes, etc, and ASP.NET 6 always returns an empty 200 even when I return an IResult from the handler.

Comment: You can make it even simpler. `app.MapGet("/api/alive", Results.NoContent);`.